# Postfix/Postgrey/openDMARC: Bypass greylisting if DMARC check succeeds

Tags: postfix, postgrey, opendmarc

I have set up Postfix so that it is using Amavis (in conjunction with Spamassassin and ClamAV), openSPF, openDKIM, and Postgrey, and I have recently added openDMARC to the configuration.
All of them are working fine, however, what I want to do now is bypass Postgrey if an incoming mail is passing the DMARC check. So far everything is subject to greylisting no matter what.

The restrictions set in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` are the following:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                                reject_invalid_hostname,
                                permit_rhswl_client swl.spamhaus.org,
                                reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
                                check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/client_restrictions,
                                check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/roleaccounts,
                                reject_unknown_client,
                                permit

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                                reject_unknown_sender_domain,
                                reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                                check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf

smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                                check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_access,
                                reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org,
                                reject_unauth_pipelining,
                                reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
                                reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
                                reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
                                permit

smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                                reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org,
                                reject_non_fqdn_sender,
                                reject_unknown_sender_domain,
                                reject_unknown_address 

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_sender,
                                reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
                                reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
                                reject_invalid_hostname,
                                permit_mynetworks,
                                reject_unauth_pipelining,
                                reject_unknown_sender_domain,
                                reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                                reject_unauth_destination,
                                reject_unknown_client,
# The next entry is Postfix accessing Postgrey...
                                check_policy_service inet:[ipv6-of-vm]:10023,
                                permit 

smtpd_etrn_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                                reject

smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining,
                                reject_multi_recipient_bounce,
                                permit
```

Setting up the milters:

```
milter_default_action = tempfail
milter_protocol = 6
# First it's openDKIM, then it's openDMARC.
smtpd_milters = inet:[ipv6-of-vm]:8891,inet:[ipv6-of-vm]:8892
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

How do I get Postfix to bypass Postgrey in case the DMARC check is passed?

Comment: I would not do that. There are enough spam senders that pass DMARC.